# Inner join returning more than 1 row from second table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables (SimCard) and (Rental_SimCard)

Simcard just contains the simcard's info like id, phonenumber, simcardnumber.

Rental_SimCard will have a record added for every simcard rental

```
Rental_SimCard - SimCardID - DateOut  - DateIn
 0              - 1         - 1/3/2017 - 1/4/2017
 1              - 1         - 1/5/2017 - 1/6/2017
 2              - 1         - 1/7/2017 - NULL
 3              - 2         - 1/7/2017 - NULL
 4              - 3         - NULL     - NULL
```

I want to display the record of simcard which have the MAX DateOut only even when DateOut is NULL

The Code I am currently using

```
    string sqlquery = "Select *, " +
        "CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN DateOut IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 THEN " +
        "MAX(DateOut) END AS MaxDateOut FROM SimCard INNER JOIN Rental_SimCard ON Rental_SimCard.SimCardID=SimCard.SimCardID " +
        "GROUP BY (Every Single Column In the two tables)
```

I group by every column because I kept getting this error

> Column 'SimCard.SimCardID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Right now my query returns a copy from the simcard table for every record recreated in the Rental_SimCard

The results I want should be

```
Rental_SimCard - SimCardID - DateOut(MAX)  - DateIn - SimCardRecords...
 2              - 1         - 1/7/2017      - NULL   - ...
 3              - 2         - 1/7/2017      - NULL   - ...
 4              - 3         - NULL          - NULL   - ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT *
FROM SimCard S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM Rental_SimCard R
             WHERE R.SimCardId=S.SimCardId
             ORDER BY DateOut DESC) T
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(Rental_SimCard)
    ,SimCard.SimCardId
    ,MAX(DATEOut)
    ,MAX(DateIn)
    ,MAX(SimCardRecords)
FROM SimCard
INNER JOIN RENTAL_SIMCARD ON SimCard.SimCardId = Rental_SimCard.SimCardID
GROUP BY SimCard.SimaCardId
```

Answer (score 1):

*Simply Make Inner Join and Group By SimCardId*

```
SELECT s.SimCardId
    ,max(Rental_SimCard)
    ,max(DATEOut)
    ,max(DateIn)
    ,max(SimCardRecords)
FROM SimCard s
INNER JOIN RENTAL_SIMCARD rs ON s.SimCardId = rs.SimCardID
GROUP BY s.SimCardId
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
select * from Rental_SimCard r inner join SimCard s
on s.SimCardID=r.SimCardID 
where 
( DateOut = (select max(DateOut) from Rental_SimCard)
or DateOut is null )
```